# During email validation through smtplib , till mxrecord it working fine but when i connect smtp with mxrecords through port 25 it gives Error

Tags: python, validation, email, smtplib

During email validation through smtplib , till mxrecord it working fine but when i connect smtp with mxrecords through port 25 it gives ( TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond ) and other than port 25 it gives (smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Pls help

```
import dns.resolver
import socket
import smtplib

records   = dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX')
mxRecord  = records[0].exchange
mxRecord  = str(mxRecord)   # MX record information

# Get local server hostname
host      = socket.gethostname()

server    = smtplib.SMTP()
server.set_debuglevel(0)


# SMTP Conversation
server.connect(mxRecord)        <----This step going to craete problem
server.helo(host)
server.mail('me@domain.com')
code, message = server.rcpt(email)
server.quit()
```

i try with all ports but nothing working